# Use of Set/Get-like Methods or a GetSet combo function

Tags: c++

I'm a fan of using C#-style `Gets` and `Sets` in classes. And then I ran into the following example: Notice the declaration of the 2nd `SetPort` in the Port Class i.e.

```
inline uint16_t & SetPort ( ) { return this->port; }
```

By using the ampersand you can create a function that can be used as both a Set and a Get, as the sample code shows. My question is, why would one want to do it this way, or conversely, why would one want to? Maybe I should have called it:

```
inline uint16_t & GetSetPort ( ) { return this->port; }
```

I understand, I think, why this works, I'm just wondering if anyone sees any utility in doing it this way, other than maybe cutting down on the number of Gets/Sets?

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

using namespace std;

class Port {
    public:

    Port ( ) { }
    Port ( const Port& orig ) { }
    virtual ~Port ( ) { }

    inline const uint16_t   GetPort ( ) { return this->port; }
    inline void             SetPort ( const uint16_t p_a ) { this->port = p_a; }
    inline uint16_t &       SetPort ( ) { return this->port; }

    protected:    
    in_port_t port;
};

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Port * p = new Port ( );

    p->SetPort ( 32);
                        cout << " Port value = " << p->GetPort () << endl;
    p->SetPort() = 64;
                        cout << " Port value = " << p->GetPort () << endl;
    p->SetPort(p->SetPort() + 32);
                        cout << " Port value = " << p->GetPort () << endl;

    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

**Results**

```
 Port value = 32
 Port value = 64
 Port value = 96
```

Comment: Since `port` is public there is no reason to have any getters or setters since anyone using it already has direct access.

Comment: (1): Returning a reference breaks encapsulation, might as well make the member variable public.  (2): Set methods without any additional code in them (other than the assignment) might as well make the member public etc.

Comment: @Richard Critten "Set methods without any additional code in them (other than the assignment) might as well make the member public" I disagree. Making a member `public` instead of having a setter that simply assigns without checks becomes a pita should the requirements later change to require a setter that does more than an assignment.

Comment: @RichardCritten Oops, you're correct, the declaration of in_port_t port should have been private... it is in the actual code.

Comment: @Swordfish can we agree to disagree. Your comment highlighted that this question is probably opinion based - flagged as such.

Comment: @JaJangMyeon try Urban Dictionary

Comment: @RichardCritten Oh, sorry, gotcha. Normally acronyms are cap'd. My bad

Comment: @Richard Critten I give you a definite maybe ;)

Comment: get/set add no value and they waste _your_ time. 
See https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

Comment: @2785528 Hyperbolic statements like "get/set add no value and they waste your time" are what are the wastes of time. You make broad assumptions about the reason why people take a certain path without any understanding of the environment they work in, corporate/government policies, etc. But I guess I understand people's need to express their opinions in a world with over 7.2 billion souls; can be lonely out there.

Comment: It has been said that get/set is the lowest level of encapsulation. A class is supposed to export public services that are natural and useful to the use of the class. So if you had a human class, would you have Food f; Human h.eat(f); or instead have h.setStomach(f); h.setPancreas(f); h.setSmallIntestine(f); h.setLargeIntestine(f);

Comment: What you (and others) find appealing about get'/set'ers quickly becomes drudgery at only slightly larger field counts. In the systems I have worked, field counts are closer to 100 (not 10). What do the 200+ functions buy you?  Get/Set'rs do not scale.  I avoid them.

Answer (score 1):

The question you want to ask yourself is "**Why do I want to use setter/getter?**".

The reasons usually are to improve encapsulation, to be able to better debug the code (you can log all sets very easily). You can also hide the implementation details (there may be "getter" but there does not have to be any *one* field behind it).

My point is if you try to save keystrokes on writing these functions and you are willing to break the encapsulation by returning a modifiable reference to your private variable outside, you are better off using plain public fields. If you, however, can see the getters and setters being useful in future, you should definitely write them with care to encapsulate your code. It is, after all, an API for your class you are designing.

To elaborate on your specific example where you return a reference so the user can set the value that way. You are kind of defeating the purpose of the setter.

- You can't check the values the user provides and for example log some special cases.
- You don't even really know when does the user set the value since he can save the reference for later and change it then.
- If you had only this single method to do both get and set, you would completely throw away *constness* of the object (you couldn't just *get* the value from a `const` instance)

When designing C++ classes I tend to use full get/set combos. When the thing I deal with is just a small data holder (usually a just a bunch of fields grouped together) I tend to use `struct` and make all the fields public.

As for the C#, in C# there is the great syntactic sugar of automatic properties, which cost pretty much nothing and are simple to write and rewrite when needed. Keep in mind, however, that these do not break the encapsulation.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for this. Exactly what I was looking for. Useful, non-pejorative and relates directly to my question!

Comment: See yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

Comment: @2785528 The blog post is worth reading, but even more so are the comments below it, which easily sum why is the author wrong and his examples are flawed (and he doesn't even respond to these comments).
The point is: no you should not write get/set all over the place pretending your class is encapsulated and no the get/set methods don't have to be trivial, they can actually do much more than just get/set private fields (and just renaming them does not make them go away).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific range of acceptable values, you still may use a get-set combo-function, without jeopardizing encapsulation:

```
#include <limits.h> // For UINT_MAX

class CPort {
public:

    CPort ( ) { }
    virtual ~CPort ( ) { }

    inline const unsigned int Port ( unsigned int port = UINT_MAX )
    {
        static_assert( UINT_MAX > 65535 ); // Just to make sure.

        if ( port <= 65535 )
            m_port = port;

        return this->m_port;
    }

protected:    
    unsigned int m_port = UINT_MAX;
};
```

And than use:

```
int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CPort P;

    P.Port(80);

    unsigned int port = P.Port(); // = UINT_MAX means: Uninitialized 

    return 0;
}
```

I am not sure if I like it.